# Is there a way to import/export tasks from different CQ instances?

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I have two instances of CQ and between them I want to be able to import/export tasks.

For example:

On instance 1 I can see all tasks by going to `http://instance1/libs/cq/taskmanagement/content/taskmanager.html#/tasks/Delta`

On instance 2 I can see all tasks by going to `http://instance2/libs/cq/taskmanagement/content/taskmanager.html#/tasks/Delta`

There might be some scenarios where I want to take all tasks from `instance2` and add them as additional tasks into instance1 (on top of the tasks it may already have).

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with Package Manager.  The tasks are stored as nodes in the JCR repository, so you can create a package that filters the task nodes you want to migrate from one instance to another.  For example, you could define a package with this filter definition to include **all** tasks:

```
/etc/taskmanagement/tasks
```

If you don't want *all* tasks, you may need to define the filter(s) more narrowly to pick only the ones you want to include.

For example:

```
/etc/taskmanagement/tasks/2015-05-04/Delta/TheTaskYouWantToMigrate
```

Use the browser when defining the filter to find the tasks you want to include.

[image]

See [Working with Packages](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/2-3/how_to/package_manager.html) for details on using the Package Manager.  This [Tutorial](http://www.cqtutorial.com/courses/cq-admin/cq-admin-lessons/cq-maintenance/cq-package-manager) also shows how to create the package and add filters.  Once you've created a package with the filters for the tasks you want to include, then build the package and download it.  On your other instance upload the package you built and install it.  You will then see the tasks one your first instance replicated onto the second instance.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what Shawn said, you also can use replication mechanisms to do the work for you, and replicate the desired nodes between any two instances.